# Media Query is triggered by lightbox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using Fancybox 2, and have a mediaquery which looks like this:

```
@media (max-width : 1200px) {

#columnset1_column1 {
    display: none;
}
#sitelayout6 {
    width: 980px !important;
}
#columnset3 {
    display: block;
}
#columnset2 {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
}
```

But the weird thing is the media query is trigger when a lightbox which shows a iframe. The page it shows is only 700 px wide.

It is only a problem in Internet Explorer, not Chrome.

The window size is not resize at any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer here that helped:
[Fancybox 2 Forcing Responsive Media Queries in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938641/fancybox-2-forcing-responsive-media-queries-in-ie)

Basically, in the iframe, update the references to your CSS to include a query string...

So in your parent page, you have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" />
```

and in your iframe, you have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css?iframe=true" />
```

This gets around a bug in IE which is causing the iframe to trigger the media query in your css for the parent page.